# Thread solution, like (animateWithDuration) completion:^

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I have animations which are (very very slightly) being knocked out of sync (late), because of the work being done immediately before them.

I have fixed this problem by putting the animations [Part 3.] inside the completion:^ method of a dummy ‘animateWithDuration’ method (duration:0).

It works *perfectly* like this:

```
[method]


    [Part 1. create series of UIImages (using CGContext) and UIImageViews /]


    [Part 2. UNNECESSARY animateWithDuration]

            completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                [Part 3. Record NSDate /]
                [Part 3. Run animations based on NSDate start time /]

            }

    [/Part 2.]


[/method]
```

What should I use instead of this unnecessary ’animateWithDuration’? Is there something equally simple but correct?

(I do not want to use a thread block for [Part 1.] which will require me to use __block pointers. I want a solution as simple as the one above, if possible.)

Comment: Maybe just create a function that runs that code inside of the dummy animation with duration in a block.

Comment: writing simple code != writing correct code. You found a workaround for your problem and it works but you should always choose the better practice for it even if it requires more effort and time.

I know you have asked for a similar answer but you should keep in mind that a solution with a proper threading is your answer, not these.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're trying to synchronize here or what you mean by "run animations," but `NSDate` is probably the wrong tool (and threads are definitely the wrong tool, though it's not clear here what you mean by "thread"). If you're trying to display images synchronized to the wall clock (to keep synchronized with audio for instance), then you want one of the real-time systems like AVPlayer or CADisplayLink. May help to explain what problem you're trying to solve. You may just need an animation transaction.

Comment: Can you post actual code that is written how you think it ought to be written?  Also, if part 1 takes a long time and is run on the main, then your app has a problem before it even gets to animate.

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to use

```
dispatch_group_t 
and
dispatch_queue_t
```

I was hoping there might be something simpler and quicker, but at least this will work.
Thanks for your comments and suggestions.